# To get last modified time in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I got the code here to search a file and its content, but how do I get the last modified time?

```
Get-ChildItem d:\* -filter $fname* | Select-String -Pattern "exit" | Write-Host - $_.Lastwritetime
```

Answer (score 5):

You already have the last modified time:

```
CreationTime   = Created
LastWriteTime  = Modified
LastAccessTime = Accessed
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more details.

I think your problem is you are using [Select-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-String) which returns a [MatchInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object and you are expecting a [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
Get-ChildItem d:* -filter $fname* | Select-String -Pattern "exit" | group path | %{ (get-item $_.Name).LastWriteTime }
```

Grouping the results of select-string by path and then  enumerating the names should give you what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dave. that worked.  before using select string if just try to print the lastwrite time will this work Get-ChildItem d:* -filter $fname* | Write-Host $_.LastWriteTime

Comment: Yes that is because fileinfo will be passed down the pipeline, by using select string you are no longer dealing with a file info object, to get the fileinfo object again we use get-item.

Comment: @user3088768 if *that worked*, would you mind accepting the answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily find out the properties by using the `Get-Member` cmdlet. For example,

```
gci test.txt | gm
# Output
   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name                      MemberType     Definition
----                      ----------     ----------
Mode                      CodeProperty   System.String Mode{get=Mode;}
AppendText                Method         System.IO.StreamWriter AppendText()
CopyTo                    Method         System.IO.FileInfo CopyTo(string destFileName)
...
```

Another way is to use GetType() to get, well, just the object's type.

```
(gci test.txt).GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                  BaseType
-------- -------- ----                  --------
True     True     FileInfo              System.IO.FileSystemInfo
```

Note the TypeName. It's a .NET class, for which David already linked [the relevant MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It's worth noting that `Get-Childitem` has *multiple* result types. That is, you'll get just a `System.IO.FileSystemInfo` when `gci` targets a file. When it targets a directory, you'll get an array of `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` objects.